# Using Lambda in Unit Test in VB.NET 2008 with Rhino.Mocks

Tags: .net, vb.net, unit-testing, lambda, rhino-mocks

I am trying to create a unit test similar to how I would have done one in C# but am struggling with the lambdas in vb.

Bascially I am trying to mock a class and then create a stub and return. In C# I would have done something like;

```
MockedPersonRepository
     .Stub(x => x.Find(id))
     .Return(person)
```

But in visual basic I am trying to do a similar thing but can not work out the syntax

```
   MockedPersonRepository.Stub(Function... argh!!!
```

Any advice on how to reproduce the above would be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards,
Dom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy example I typically show (as I'm a VB developer also) is the below: (for some odd reason in VB you need to pull this out into another function that returns nothing)

```
  <TestMethod()> _
  Public Sub Should_Call_Into_Repository_For_GetAllUsers()
    Dim Repository As IUserRepository = MockRepository.GenerateStub(Of IUserRepository)()
    Dim Service As IUserService = New UserService(Repository)

    Service.GetAllUserCollection()

    Repository.AssertWasCalled(Function(x) Wrap_GetAllUserCollection(x))
  End Sub

Function Wrap_GetAllUserCollection(ByVal Repository As IUserRepository) As Object
    Repository.GetAllUserCollection()

    Return Nothing
  End Function
```

The above is for interaction based testing, the below might be closer to what you are looking for in your current example

```
Dim StubUserObject As New User(1, "9999", "jdoe", "John", "Doe", 1)

    UserService.Stub(Function(x) x.GetUserByID(1)).[Return](StubUserObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
MockedPersonRepository_
    .Stub(Function(x) x.Find(id))_
    .[Return](person)
```